# Linux Server offline briefly every 30 minutes and 10 seconds

Tags: networking, ping

I have a very odd situation with a Linux Server (Fedora 38) that goes offline exactly every 30 minutes and 10 seconds. Nothing can ping it and it can't ping anything for a second or two, then it's fine again for another 30 minutes and 10 seconds.

Now, it's not a show stopper but I'd just like to get to the bottom of it and I've pretty much exhausted what I can try next.

I have TCPDump run for 20 seconds starting 10 seconds before I know the server will go offline, and there's nothing obvious in there.

I check running services and there's nothing odd there either.

Does anybody have any idea as to what is going on and what I can check next?

Thanks, Andy

Comment: So, how does it look like — traffic is coming to the server but it doesn't answer it? Traffic doesn't come into the server at all? Traffic generated on the server — shows up on wire or doesn't? Shows up on destination or not? If you ran tcpdump you should answer these pretty easily.

Comment: Offline how? Link down? Does it answer to ARP? Pingable? Application/web server offline? What do the logs say?

Comment: >> So, how does it look like 

At the moment, all I have tested for is that it does not respond to a ping from any device on the network. Almost like the interface goes down but then come back up again before anything complains.

>> Offline how? Link down? Does it answer to ARP? Pingable?

It’s not pingable, but I fear it just doesn’t respond to anything. I will run some more tests.

Answer (score 0):

What does "nothing obvious in there" mean?

Presumably you have checked the logs to ensure that the host was up, the network was connected and it had an assigned IP address during the window? If it really is 1810 seconds BETWEEN the START of each incident (rather than 1800 seconds THEN 10 seconds of downtime) this suggests it is not a scheduled task.

Given the information you have provided then the most likely candidate is a temperamental DHCP configuration. But you already checked the logs?

You forgot to tell us if you have anything else on the same network / what is between where you are monitoring the host and the host itself. You also forgot to tell us how long it was offline for.

I'd be tempted to run ping/ip a/iptables -L on the host at frequent intervals spanning an incident.

Comment: >> What do the logs say?

Nothing, the logs don’t show anything. It never times out though, it comes back up soon after so never exceeds a timeout to force a log entry.

>> What does "nothing obvious in there" mean?

Just that I could not see anything that jumped out at me. It does show the successful pings from the test server but obviously won’t show the one that failed because they never reach the server.

I’m beginning to think this might be firewall related. Something is maybe reloading the firewall every 30 minutes but why the 10 second shift?

Comment: You've just repeated what you said in the first place. What you SHOULD have been looking for is whether there was ANY activity recorded during the window to establish if the host was still running rather than having no CPU to run on.

Comment: The host is running fine, it just looses network briefly and the more I look it is VERY brief. All the servers have static IP addresses so it's not a DHCP issue. All servers are on the same switch but only one has the issue. Also, I have now tested the servers firewall with debugging on and it's not the firewall. However, this issue is very much like a firewall reload but it's not the problem.

Comment: If the host were "losing network" your logs should be full of events. Based on your description of events the issue is not arising on the host. It is merely uncontactable.